# Error during launch ITK/VTK project on ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, vtk, itk

I am trying to launch a ITK/VTQ project with Qt. The project runs on Windows 10, but not on Ubuntu.

I have the following error during launching the project:

```
X Error: BadColor (invalid Colormap parameter) 12
  Major opcode: 1 (X_CreateWindow)
  Resource id:  0x4a00001
```

How I can correct this error message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running other OpenGL applications/games? There could be a problem with 3D graphics drivers on your Ubuntu. Also, without source code fragment for window creation, I doubt anyone can help you much further.